# How to load different stylesheets depending on the template

Tags: templates, channel, template-layouts, stylesheets

Right now I have an includes.group, that holds different templates that I load. Such as the nav, head, footer etc.

As of right now the head holds all of my style sheets for every template. But I would like a way to only load certain style sheets depending on the template.

How can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest and and most flexible way is to use Template [Layouts](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/layouts.html).

In your main HTML Layout wrapper (simplified) which we will say is named "_html-layout" in the "layouts" template group:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/global.css">
    {layout:css_extra}
<head>
<body>
    {layout:contents}
</body>
</html>
```

In your templates, identify which layout it will use, and set the `css_extra` layout variable.:

```
{layout="layouts/_html-layout"}

{layout:set name="css_extra"}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/contact-form.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/form-validation.css">
{/layout:set}
```

`{layout:css_extra}` in the layout will get the extra stylesheets, and everything else that the template outputs will become `{layout:contents}`.

Comment: Not sure what it has to do with template routes (i think nothing at all!).  Use layout templates, using layout variables to pass the CSS entries is very efficient, and a better solution than using an embed.

Comment: wrote this in a hurry, since i was baking pizza's ;-) you're right it's layout templates, not routes. silly me

Answer (score 0):

How we do that: in your embed call, create some variables and pass the stylesheet names that you want to load, then pass those into the template.

```
{embed="template_group/template" stylesheet="mystylesheet.css"}
```

and in the template:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/{embed:mystylesheet}">
</head>
```